# anaconda & python's HTML documentation

Tags: python, anaconda

Is it possible to install a copy of Python's tree of HTML documentation, for offline browsing, in the frame of an Anaconda Python installation?

---

Edit:

following [juanpa-arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485501/anaconda-pythons-html-documentation?noredirect=1#comment72110417_42485501) (thank you juanpa for the heads up)

> What do you mean "in the frame of an Anaconda Python installation"?

I mean that I'd like to install the official Python documentation using s/t alike

```
$ conda install python-docs
```

and have the documentation installed into the anaconda tree, managed by anaconda tools and (possibly) accessible offline directly from the Jupyter notebook or `conda-navigator`

Comment: What do you mean "in the frame of an Anaconda Python installation"? Is [this download](https://docs.python.org/3/download.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've replied in the body of the question, thank you for pointing at one of the weaknesses of my question

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Btw, I can install the material available at your link using the package management system of my distribution, the question is specific to the Anaconda Python distribution.